# Google Lens image search on mobile by URL

Tags: deep-linking, google-image-search

We have made an app where users can upload a profile photo. We want to make sure that the photos are of the users themselves and not celebrities or memes, so we send out a mail to moderators every time a photo is uploaded with a link to https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=... . This works great on desktop, but on mobile the link gives a 404, with or without the Google app installed.

Does anyone know why, or have a link that works on mobile as well?

Comment: We decided to use Google's Web Detection API instead to automatically reject images that are recognised from around the web. Works great.

Comment: We also found that Bing image search works on all platforms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found a solution that still works from mobile (it's not Google Lens but traditional Google Image search):

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?sbisrc=4chanx&image_url=%IMG&safe=off
```

replace %IMG with your image URL.

By the way, as you've mentioned Bing, here is my "collection" of revers image search links:

```
search_engines = {"GOOGLE": ["https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?sbisrc=4chanx&image_url=", "&safe=off"],
                      "GOOGLE LENS (from desktop only!)": ["https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=", ""],
                       "YANDEX": ["https://yandex.ru/images/touch/search?rpt=imageview&url=", ""],
                       "BING": ["https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailv2&iss=sbi&form=SBIVSP&sbisrc=UrlPaste&q=imgurl:", ""],
                       "TINEYE": ["https://www.tineye.com/search/?url=", ""],
                       "IQDB": ["https://iqdb.org/?url=", ""],
                       "SAUCEANO": ["https://saucenao.com/search.php?db=999&url=", ""],
                       "IMGOPS": ["https://imgops.com/", ""]
                       }
```

every dict's value is a pair of prefix / suffix: put your image's URL between them.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you. We decided to use the web detection API instead though but this is good for extra moderation.